# Common::PID settings (joint unable to lift a weight)

Tags: gazebo-6

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,

I am trying to simulate a robot which must lift an object from the ground.

I use a prismatic joint controlled with a plugin. I use JointController class and functions like SetPositionTarget to control it.

When I send a position without an object to lift, the target position is reached. But when I have an object to lift, the target position is not reached. I tried to tune PID values but even with very high values the target position is not reached. I checked the effort limit and the effort sent to the link is ten time lower to the limit (so no limitation from the model).

Is it just a pid settings problem or is there another way to do it.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/12886/common::pid-settings-(joint-unable-to-lift-a-weight)/) by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 284 on 2016-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hades208002](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3296/hades208002/) on 2017-05-22**:
could you please show me your code of this question? i am building a robot like this as a homework, but i have no idea how to do this:(, thank you a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Here are typical steps for setting PID gains empirically (aka by trial and error):

1. Increase your P gain until the actual value reaches the desired value in the desired amount of time (rise time).  This will typically result in large oscillations that take a while to settle down... but that will be fixed later.  For now, just focus on rise time.  Make sure that your P is low enough that the system remains stable (aka the oscillations die off after a certain amount of time).  If your actual value will not reach your desired value no matter how high you set your P gain, skip to step 3.
2. Increase your D gain to reduce the oscillations until you reach your desired settling time (aka the time it takes for the oscillations to fall below +/- 5% of the desired value).  Be careful here, D gains are very sensitive and can cause very noisy responses, especially when you are working with a discrete system with relatively large time steps (like in simulation).
3. If your system has steady state error (aka no value of P gain can get the actual value to reach the desired value), start increasing your I gain until the steady state error disappears in a satisfactory amount of time.
4. Repeat steps 1-3 to continuously fine tune the PID controller.

The general idea here is to start with small gains, and run through these steps several times, changing the gains a little bit each time.  Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [pcdangio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/257/pcdangio/) with karma: 207 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Brosseau.F](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2389/brosseau.f/) on 2016-03-22**:
Thanks to both of you guys. I manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. Try higher values. Keep increasing the values until it moves.
2. Make sure the inertia of the object is correct.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1